# How to have a mysql query print out in bootstrap cards alongside each other

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a mysql query of results to print out alongside each other, say 3 in a row and not one below the other.

I have tried stack overlow answers and I cannot find one that helps

```
    <?php

    include('db.php');
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM contacts");
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])){


    $id = $_GET['edit'];
      $edit_state = true;
      $rec =mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id=$id ");
      $record = mysqli_fetch_array($rec);
      $name = $record['name'];
      $contact = $record['contact'];
      $email = $record['email'];
      $id = 

    $record['id'];
    }?>

    <div class="container">

        <h1 class="my-4">Welcome to Modern Business</h1>

        <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->

        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){ ?>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">

              <h4 class="card-header"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
              <img class="img_size" src="images/dog2.jpg" alt="Card image top">
              <div class="card-body">

                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></p>

              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
          <?php } ?>
```

right now, the cards are printing out but not inline, one below the other. I would like them to print horizontally.

any help at all would be appreciated, I am new to php.

[This is the wrong outcome, I want them beside each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDBsf.png)

Comment: Do you want to make it horizontal or vertical? I think you are trying to make it horizontal, right?

Comment: yes, horizontally sorry, head is a little all over the place with it.

Comment: please be show sample output.

Comment: Ok. Wait, I'll share it with

Comment: thankyou any help would be appreciated, playing with it for hours

Comment: Thank you Dharman, I will look into this

Comment: @Mariam have your output is come with my answer?????

Comment: Yes, thank you for your  help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code:

```
<?php 
include('dbconn.php');   // include database connection 

$output="";
$selQuery = "select * from tbl_name";
$exeQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$selQuery);

$output="<h2>Welcome to Modern Business
            <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exeQuery)) {
             $name = $row['name'];
             $desciption = $row['desciption'];
             $ephoto = $row['ephoto'];

            $output.="<div class='col-sm-4'>
           <h4 class='card-header'>$name</h4>
           <img class='img_size' src='$ephoto' alt='Card image top'>
           <p>$desciption</p>
           <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Learn More</a>
        </div>";     
    }    
    $output.="</div></div></h2>";
 echo $output;  

 ?>
```

HTML markup including bootstrap links:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, it prints them in the correct position, but the same data from each record repeated on row one, then row two and so on.

Comment: I will post the outcome as an answer with a screenshot

Comment: yes this is  the desired output of this code , so what you actually want ?

Comment: I wanted each data record to print out individually alongside each other (one of each) but not below each other. (not repeating)

Comment: I will show you the outcome that I would like in another answer in one minute

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the while loop before the following `div` and end it when `div` ends.

```
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){ ?>
  <div class="card h-100">
    <h4 class="card-header">
  <?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
    <img class="img_size" src="images/dog2.jpg" alt="Card image top">
   <div class="card-body">
     <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></p> </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
Learn More
      </a>
     </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Also replace `col-lg-4` with `col-lg-12`
**Try this and update me.**

Comment: Also replace col-lg-4 with col-lg-12

Comment: Saularis, I have tried both and neither are successful. logically i thought the same as you, and it seems it should work like that with the while loop before the div. But they still print out the same way,

Comment: Did you replace col-lg-4?

Comment: Yes, it just makes the image bigger. but still prints them out the same way